# How to unselect mysql default database?

Tags: mysql, database, default

Thanks to `USE 'db_name'` i can select MySQL default database.

But i can't find out, how to unselect default database. So, that `DATABASE()` statement return `none`.

Answer (score 0):

1. you have to customize your constructors pro grammatically where default constructors initialize your default database where else your parametric constructors getting custom database.
2. Use Stored Procedures.

Comment: No, i mean, there is USE 'db_name' statement to set default database. Is there another, similar statement, that unset default database?